# Downloading iOS Developer Enterprise Program Applications

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I'm looking for a mechanism to allow our employees and a select few key business partners to download a copy of our Beta iOS app without having to register for TestFlight or register their device in one of our provisioning profiles to use a service such as Crashlytics.

Can the iOS Developer Enterprise Program achieve this? If we build an app using the enterprise provisioning profile would anyone with a link to the .ipa be able to install this app on their iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Using enterprise profile you don't need to add UDID of devices in it, you can make build using it and achieve from XCode. Then it can be installed in any iOS device.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, i'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

TestFlight is integrated in iTunesConnect, so you can use iTunesConnect for managing a BetaCommunity. Advantage is that you keep better control as the apps expire after 30 days.

If you deploy apps build with enterprise certificate you can not prevent abuse ... everyone in the world can install these ipa-files.